# segmentation fault when assigning NULL to child Node in BinaryTree

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct BTreeNode BTNode;
struct BTreeNode
{
int value;
struct BTreeNode *left_child,*right_child;
};

int insert(int input_value, BTNode *head_node)
{
    BTNode *temp,*head;
    temp->value = input_value;
    temp->left_child = NULL;
    temp->right_child = NULL;
    head = head_node;
//  while(1)
    {
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
//          break;
            return 0;
        }
        if(temp->value > head->value)
        {
            head = head->right_child;
        }
        else if(temp->value < head->value)
        {
            head = head->left_child;
        }
        else
        {
//          break;
        }
            printf("Inserted successfully\n");
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    BTNode *root=NULL;
    insert(23,root);
}
```

I am trying to insert a new value in a Binary search tree.
In the following code I am getting segmentation fault at "temp->left_child = NULL;" line in insert function. I dont understand why I am getting that could anyone please help me out ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `temp = malloc (sizeof (BTNode))`.

You never allocated space
for where `temp` points to, so it's trying to save data to memory
that doesn't belong to it. This lead to unexpected behaviour. You
are lucky that you got segmentation fault.

Note: how do you plan to change the root of the tree? I cannot
figure this from your code. Perhaps you can return the root node
every time from your function like: `BTNode* insert(int input_value, BTNode *head_node)`
or use a double pointer like: `int insert(int input_value, BTNode **head_node)` and
do `*head_node` inside `insert`. Have a look [here](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/) for a good read about pointers
and memory allocation in C.

Comment: As we are working on pointers can't we use the root in main as root forever as we are inserting values considering root as root of binary tree ???

Comment: I mean to say is that changes done on pointers will have global scope.so do we need to return root again ??

Answer (score 0):

Sure, memory allocation is missing.  You pass an argument `root` which is NULL to your function, and then you declare a pointer `temp` without any memory allocation, after that you dereference it -- no good.

Answer (score 0):

```
BTNode *temp,*head;
temp->value = input_value;
```

Temp is being used without allocating space. So it should be:

```
BTNode *temp,*head;
temp = malloc(sizeof(BTreeNode));
temp->value = input_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no memory allocated to temp. You should do it like :

```
BTNode * createNode()
{
return ((node *)malloc(sizeof(node)));
} 

int insert(int input_value, BTNode *head_node)
{
    BTNode *temp,*head;
    temp = createNode();
    temp->value = input_value;
    temp->left_child = NULL;
    temp->right_child = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocate memory to temporary Node first.It should be like this,

```
BTNode *temp,*head;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(BTNode));
    temp->value = input_value;
    temp->left_child = NULL;
    temp->right_child = NULL;
```